# SQL SERVER order by a mathematical operation between fields

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Hello I have a table with MLB 2019 Results and trying to create Standings. I created the code in MySQL and works fine but the same code in SQL Server has error in the ORDER BY clause. The problem is the Wins/(Wins+Losses) operation because it says there is no "Wins" and "Losses" columns I know that I can write Wins/(Wins+Losses) AS Ratio in the select statement but I don't want to see Ratio column next to Wins-Losses in my Result. Any Idea?

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Invalid column name 'Wins'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Invalid column name 'Wins'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Invalid column name 'Losses'.

```
Select a1.Team,a1.HomeWins+a2.AwayWins as Wins,a1.HomeLoses+a2.AwayLoses 
as Losses 
FROM 
(select t0.Team, t0.HomeWins,t1.HomeLoses from (select home as 
Team,count(home) as HomeWins from mlbreg
where homescore>awayscore
group by home) t0  INNER JOIN (select home as Team,count(home) as 
HomeLoses from mlbreg
where homescore<awayscore
group by home) t1 on t0.Team=t1.Team) a1
INNER JOIN 
(select t2.Team, t2.AwayWins,t3.AwayLoses from (select away as 
Team,count(away) as AwayWins from mlbreg
where homescore<awayscore
group by away) t2  INNER JOIN (select away as Team,count(away) as 
AwayLoses from mlbreg
where homescore>awayscore
group by away) t3 on t2.Team=t3.Team) a2 on a1.Team=a2.Team  
order by (Wins/(Wins+Losses)) desc;
```

Comment: is this for mysql or for sql-server ?

Comment: @GuidoG I created for MySQL but tried to execute it in SQL-Server. the error was in SQL-Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
Select a1.Team,a1.HomeWins+a2.AwayWins as Wins,a1.HomeLoses+a2.AwayLoses 
as Losses 
FROM 
(select t0.Team, t0.HomeWins,t1.HomeLoses from (select home as 
Team,count(home) as HomeWins from mlbreg
where homescore>awayscore
group by home) t0  INNER JOIN (select home as Team,count(home) as 
HomeLoses from mlbreg
where homescore<awayscore
group by home) t1 on t0.Team=t1.Team) a1
INNER JOIN 
(select t2.Team, t2.AwayWins,t3.AwayLoses from (select away as 
Team,count(away) as AwayWins from mlbreg
where homescore<awayscore
group by away) t2  INNER JOIN (select away as Team,count(away) as 
AwayLoses from mlbreg
where homescore>awayscore
group by away) t3 on t2.Team=t3.Team) a2 on a1.Team=a2.Team  
order by ((a1.HomeWins+a2.AwayWins)/((a1.HomeWins+a2.AwayWins)+(a1.HomeLoses+a2.AwayLoses))) desc;
```

Comment: We have explicitly mention in select query to order by ratio. So, it is not possible that  query is again returning data order by Team. Can you tell your whole story? Are you saving this select query result somewhere.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Your code works perfect thanks!